# Assembla Git project dependency/merge

Tags: git, assembla

I am using assembla/git.
Goal:
I want to host 2 different projects on assembla: Common project and my NewProject.
Common is used by several developers and they might edit and commit changes to it.
Only I work on NewProject, this NewProject use Common as external resource, what i mean is that when I want to pull NewProject from assembla, I also want to get the latest Common files that are on different project in assembla.
Is this possible ? I think maybe the phrase is to "merge between projects" ?
I am new to git/assembla, used to work with tortoise SVN till now
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can create a merge request from your main project to your personal project whether your project is in the same space or in another space.

To set this up you want to fork your main project to a new repo from your git tool under Fork Network.  Then when you are ready to merge from your main repo to your personal project, you want to go to submit code from your git tool of your main repo to setup the Merge Request.